# how to use use class method name inside method itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection, method-names

Is there better way to get function name inside the class.

I would like to get and `<str> "A.boo"` without using `self.boo` statement.

this is the `test.py` which I ran

```py
import sys
import traceback

def foo():
    print(foo.__name__)
    print(foo.__qualname__)
    print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name)
    print(traceback.extract_stack()[-2])


foo()

class A:
    def boo(self):
        print(self.boo.__name__)
        print(self.boo.__qualname__)
        print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name)
        print(traceback.extract_stack()[-2])

A().boo()
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
foo
foo
foo
<FrameSummary file test.py, line 12 in <module>>
boo
A.boo
boo
<FrameSummary file test.py, line 21 in <module>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import inspect


class A:
    def boo(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__, end=“.”)
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
```

Another way:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def prints_merhod_name(method, *args, **kwargs):
    self = args[0]
    print(self.__class__.__name__, method.__name__, sep=“.”)
    return method(*args, **kwargs)


class A:
    @prints_method_name
    def foo(self):
    whatever
```